# Flutter hivebox HiveError: Box has already been closed

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am using this function to make sure to open and close box appropriately
but i am still getting `HiveError: Box has already been closed.` error

```
static Future<Box<dynamic>> openIt() async {
    var connectionBox = await Hive.openBox(hiveBox);
    if (Hive.isBoxOpen(hiveBox) == false) {
      await Hive.openBox(hiveBox);
     
    } else {
      await connectionBox.close();
      connectionBox = await Hive.openBox(hiveBox);
      
    }

    return connectionBox;
  }
```

How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: facing the same issue i think its a bug

Comment: I am also facing this issue. The box closes after 2 minutes.

Comment: maybe try closing box like this : await connectionBox.close(hiveBox);

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why, but using that method without the static keyword and running it fixed it for me.

```
static Future<Box<dynamic>> openIt() async { // no

Future<Box<dynamic>> openIt() async { // yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "Hive.isBoxOpen" is unnecessary code in your function.

And I change a few things in your code;

```
static Future<Box<dynamic>> openIt() async {
  var connectionBox = Hive.box<dynamic>(hiveBox);
  if (!connectionBox.isOpen) {
    connectionBox = await Hive.openBox<dynamic>(hiveBox);
  }

  return connectionBox;
}
```

Cloud you try this function?

Answer (score 0):

According to official [HiveDocs](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/boxes?id=close-box)

> It is perfectly fine to leave a box open for the runtime of the app. If you need a box again in the future, just leave it open.

and

> Before your application exits, you should call Hive.close() to close all open boxes. Don't worry if the app is killed before you close Hive, it doesn't matter.

So don't always close the box. Only close it on application exit or SignOut, depending on the scenario.